# Seeking Typescript Type Definition new + callable clarification

Tags: typescript

My issue arises from attempting to add a TypeScript type definition `.d.ts` to a 3rd party library. Keep in mind I do not control this library, I am simply trying to consume it and appease the tsc compiler.

Reading the guidelines here re: writing `d.ts` files:

https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Writing%20Definition%20%28.d.ts%29%20Files

I am looking at this specific example: **New + callable methods**

Here, the documentation shows the following pattern:

```
interface Widget {
    sprock(): void;
}

interface WidgetFactory {
    new(name: string): Widget;
    (width: number, height: number): Widget;
}

declare var widget: WidgetFactory;
```

Building on this I have created the following for my needs:

```
declare module "react-localization" {
    interface LocalizedStringsMethods {
        setLanguage(language: string): void;
        getLanguage(): string;
        getInterfaceLanguage(): string;
        formatString(str: string, ...values: any[]): string
        getAvailableLanguages(): string[]
    }

    interface LocalizedStringsFactory {
        new (props: any): LocalizedStringsMethods;
    }

    var LocalizedStrings: LocalizedStringsFactory;

    export default LocalizedStrings;
}
```

The notable exception here is the documentation version does not use `declare module`. Aside from that, to my eye, these SHOULD be the same an yield a similar result; I am clearly missing something. I get the following error instead:

**error TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.**

I can change my definition to this:

```
declare module "react-localization" {
    var LocalizedStrings: any;
    export = LocalizedStrings;
}
```

The error is now gone, but I lose all the wonderful type information. =,(

I am at a loss. What exactly am doing wrong here?

Ok to add to the mystery, I tried doing `export =` in the fuller type example instead of `export default`:

```
declare module "react-localization" {
    interface LocalizedStringsMethods {
        setLanguage(language: string): void;
        getLanguage(): string;
        getInterfaceLanguage(): string;
        formatString(str: string, ...values: any[]): string
        getAvailableLanguages(): string[]
    }

    interface LocalizedStringsFactory {
        new (props: any): LocalizedStringsMethods;
    }

    var LocalizedStrings: LocalizedStringsFactory;

    export = LocalizedStrings; // <----- HERE instead of export default
}
```

Can someone explain to me why this works but `export default` ends up returning `undefined`?  Also, I have to import this like:

`import * as LocalizedStrings from 'react-localization'` I'd prefer to do the import as `import LocalizedStrings from 'react-localization`. At this point I'll live with the former, I'd just like to understand why.

Comment: additionally it looks like it's relevant that this 3rd party lib is compiled from babel: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5565 `When Babel transpiles a module whose only export is an export default it injects a module.exports = exports["default"]; into the generated code, causing the exported object to become the function itself (instead of a module object that has the function as the default property).`

Answer (score 1):

Solution is:

`react-localization.d.ts`

```
declare module "react-localization" {
    interface LocalizedStringsMethods {
        setLanguage(language: string): void;
        getLanguage(): string;
        getInterfaceLanguage(): string;
        formatString(str: string, ...values: any[]): string
        getAvailableLanguages(): string[]
    }

    interface LocalizedStringsFactory {
        new (props: any): LocalizedStringsMethods;
    }

    var LocalizedStrings: LocalizedStringsFactory;

    export default LocalizedStrings;
}
```

`yourFile.ts`

```
import LocalizedStrings from 'react-localization';

var x = new LocalizedStrings(123);
```

If you want to use `export =` then `import = require()` should be used. More details in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Comment: Turns out it's nuanced. Because this lib `react-localization`, is transpiled from babel, per Anders explanation in http://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5565, babel is doing this: `module.exports = exports["default"];` setting the whole module to the function, which under default import in Typescript is trying to do this: `function(){...}.default` which is indeed `undefined`.  Thus, `import * as Thing from 'thing` is required. Removing this line `module.exports = exports["default"];`  allows typescript to effectively: `{default: <func>}.default` aka: `import Thing from 'thing' `

Comment: @adam-venturella yes, thanks for raising this problem up. Unfortunately I don't have boilerplate to play with real Babel results. And sorry if my answer is irrelevant